# The application does not start (error due to _stprintf_s)

Tags: c++

When I execute code in Visual studio 2015, I get the following message
**Triggered a breakpoint.** 
It seems that the error occurs in stdio.h at line 1265

```
{
    int const _Result = __stdio_common_vswprintf_s( // this is line 1265
        _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_PRINTF_OPTIONS,
        _Buffer, _BufferCount, _Format, _Locale, _ArgList);

    return _Result < 0 ? -1 : _Result;
}
```

Problem in this line, but I cannot understand why?

```
_stprintf_s(info_temp, _T("\r\n%s"), infoBuf);
```

Here is my code:

```
    TCHAR* envVarStrings[] =
{
    TEXT("OS         = %OS%"),
    TEXT("PATH       = %PATH%"),
    TEXT("HOMEPATH   = %HOMEPATH%"),
    TEXT("TEMP       = %TEMP%")
};
#define  ENV_VAR_STRING_COUNT  (sizeof(envVarStrings)/sizeof(TCHAR*))
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767

void main()
{
    DWORD i;
    TCHAR  infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
    ...
    bufCharCount = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(envVarStrings[1], infoBuf,
            INFO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        TCHAR info_temp[MAX_PATH];
        _stprintf_s(info_temp, _T("\r\n%s"), infoBuf);
        SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_EDIT), info_temp);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `_stprintf_s` correctly. The second argument should be the size of the destination string.

```
_stprintf_s(info_temp, MAX_PATH, _T("\r\n%s"), infoBuf);
```

Comment: `MAX_PATH` is the maximum number of characters in a file path, not the maximum size of the `PATH` variable. Is the value of `bufCharCount` returned by `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` less than `MAX_PATH` (the size of the `info_temp` string)?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, I did not immediately take into account a very long line. I changed the `TCHAR info_temp[10000]` And the program has earned. Big thanks!
PS. One thousand also was not enough :/